# Updating a row in the database from the modal using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `calls table` that is populated from a form,

**calls table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('calls', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->text('terminal_id', 20);
        $table->text('terminal_name', 100);
        $table->text('fault_description');
        $table->string('call_status', 10)->default('New call');
        $table->text('assigned_FE', 20)->nullable();
        $table->text('closed_on', 20)->nullable();
        $table->text('closed_by', 50)->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

I want to fetch and update only the `assigned_FE` column in my `calls table` with a user's entry on this modal form

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="{{route('Call.update')}}" method="POST" style="padding:30px 0px">

        @csrf
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                <label for="assigned_FE">{{ __('Name of field engineer') }}</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="assigned_FE" id="assigned_FE" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of field engineer" style="padding: 20px;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 14px; border: 0; margin-top:25px">{{ __('Submit') }}</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

How do I achieve this without fetching all the data in a call's row?
I don't have an idea of what to place in my `CallsController` 
This is my `CallsController`

```
public function edit($id)
{
//find the call in the db and save it as a variable
$call = Call::find($id);
//return it to the view and pass in the variable


}

/**
* Update the specified resource in storage.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @param  int  $id
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
//
}
```

and here is my Calls model (`Call.php`)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Call extends Model{

    protected $fillable = [
        'terminal_id',
        'terminal_name',
        'branch_address',
        'fault_description'
      ];
    //describing a one-to-many-relationship between calls and users
    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

Comment: You have to add update route and then update function in the controller. Can you add what you have done so far

Comment: Have you created a `Call` Eloquent model?

Comment: I just included  the controller and model in the question

Comment: am still getting the same error even when I have included the id...it seems it's still not reading the id what could be the cause? is it from my controller or the route

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first in your Model you should include all column name in the fillable array your Call model is missing assigned_FE

```
class Call extends Model{

protected $fillable = [
    'terminal_id',
    'terminal_name',
    'branch_address',
    'atm_variant',
    'assigned_FE',
    'closed_on',
    'closed_by',
    'fault_description'
  ];
//describing a one-to-many-relationship between calls and users
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
```

}

after making sure that all columns are present in the fillable array, change your Form action to point to call.update route

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form action="{{route('call.update')}}" method="POST" style="padding:30px 0px">

    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
            <label for="assigned_FE">{{ __('Name of field engineer') }}</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="assigned_FE" id="assigned_FE" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of field engineer" style="padding: 20px;" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 14px; border: 0; margin-top:25px">{{ __('Submit') }}</button>
</form>
```

your controller

```
use App\Call;
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
$assigned_FE = $request->assigned_FE;
$call = Call::findOrFail($id); 
$call->assigned_FE = $assigned_FE;
$call-save();

return redirect()->back();

}
```

your routes file should have something like this:

```
route::post('call/{id}', CallsController@update)->name('call.update);
```

Comment: this is the error message I get when I try to submit the form `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CallsController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: I updated my answer (route section), make sure you are passing the Call id

Answer (score 0):

Here you go If I try to understand your question!

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  if($request->isMethod('post')){
  $data = $request->all();

  //this part will get your item with that specific id updated just match database columns with form input names.
  call::where(['id'=> $id])
  ->update(['terminal_name'=> $data['terminal_name'], 'fault_description' =>$data['fault_description']]);

  //redirected to another page after updating or
  //return back(); to stay on same page.
  return redirect('/page');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code (not to the comment section) such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Get the required record in the `update` function and then update it.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $call = Call::find($id);

    $input = $request->all();

    $call->assigned_FE = $input['assigned_FE'];
    $call->update();

    // redirect wherever you want
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: This is the error message I get when I try to submit the form  `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CallsController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: As you can see in the update function there are 2 variables it expects.  A $request, and an $id.  If you are only passing one of the two that is your issue.